# Stereo buzzing noise when lights not on; recently installed reversing camera

Tags: audio, backup-camera, interference

I have an Xtrons stereo head unit.  I have attached a reversing camera that switches the camera image to the head unit automatically when I put the vehicle into reverse and switches back again when I release from reverse.

If the external lights ***are not*** on, there is a buzzing noise when I put the car into reverse.  If the external lights ***are*** on, there is no buzzing noise!

The camera's picture is perfect whether the lights are on or not.

I have checked all connections including the `earth` which is connected to the body of the vehicle is good.

Any ideas on how I can get rid of the noise?

Comment: How have you wired the camera, what feeds have you wired into?
Where is the noise coming from?
What external lights, reverse lights, parking lights etc etc?

Comment: I have wired the positive in the reverse trigger behind the stereo which is part of the ISO connection. Camera end, I have spliced into the reverse light.  The noise is coming from the actual head unit (that vicinity), not the car speakers. The buzzing/feedback doesn't happen when the the vehicle sidelights or headlights are on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some systems especially ones intended for commercial vehicles include a warning buzzer to indicate that the vehicle is about to reverse to warn bystanders. This is often overridden if the lights are on to avoid causing a nuisance late at night and because the buzzer is less needed in the dark when the reversing lights are  more obvious.

Another possibility is that in many newer vehicles a light cluster has a single common power supply and individual lights are switched on and off with a low current signal voltage. This can sometimes cause odd effects with electrical systems which are spliced into the lighting circuit. Similarly these may also include a bulb failure warning system which detects usual loads so the buzzing could be an audible bulb failure warning or it could just be that the system isn't getting the right voltage/current.

In this case the solution is to take a power supply either direct from the battery or some other convenient source which can supply adequate current and voltage and put a relay between the feed from the reversing light and the camera so you are not putting any extra load on the lighting circuit.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look tomorrow and i'm assuming the 2nd possibility is likely to be the case based on the Haynes manual. I'll let you know, thanks again.